# Package exception while deploying azure service fabric guest executable

Tags: azure-service-fabric, guest-executable

I am trying to deploy a guest executable but that executable is in a subfolder of my code directory like this below is xml snippet from my ServiceManifest.xml

```
   <EntryPoint>
         <ExeHost>
           <Program>Anaconda\python.exe</Program>
           <Arguments>InitialFiltering\back_testing_agent_python_consumer.py</Arguments>
           <WorkingFolder>CodeBase</WorkingFolder>
           <!-- Uncomment to log console output (both stdout and stderr) to one of the
                service's working directories. -->
           <!-- <ConsoleRedirection FileRetentionCount="5" FileMaxSizeInKb="2048"/> -->
         </ExeHost>
   </EntryPoint>
```

but whenever i try to deploy it upon my local cluster it throws

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.ApplicationProject.ProjectSystem.PackageException

. however if the exe is directly under the code folder like this

> `<Program>python.exe</Program>`

then it works fine